# Prob. 32, Chap. 7, in Schaum's GENERAL TOPOLOGY: $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}\left(A^o\right)\subset \left( f^{-1}(A) \right)^o$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ be any topological spaces. Prove that $f \colon X \longrightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1} \left( A^o \right) \subset \left( f^{-1}(A) \right)^o$ for every set $A \subset Y$.

[ PS:

Here $S^o$ denotes the interior of $S$ in the appropriate embedding space.]

Proof:

Suppose that $f \colon X \longrightarrow Y$ is continuous. Let $A$ be any subset of $Y$. Then since
$A^o \subset A$ and $A^o$ is open in $Y$, we have $f^{-1} \left( A^o \right) \subset f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}\left(A^o \right)$ is an open set in $X$, and therefore by the definition of the interior of a set as the union of all the open subset of that set we can conclude that
$$
f^{-1} \left( A^o \right) \subset \left( f^{-1}(A) \right)^o,
$$
as required.

Am I right?

Conversely, suppose that $f^{-1} \left( A^o \right) \subset \left( f^{-1}(A) \right)^o$ for every subset $A$ of $Y$. Let $V$ be any open set of $Y$. Then we have $V^o = V$, and so
$$
f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1} \left( V^o \right) \subset \left( f^{-1} (V) \right)^o,
$$
which implies that
$$
f^{-1}(V) = \left( f^{-1} (V) \right)^o,
$$
thus showing that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. Therefore $f \colon X \longrightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Am I right?

Is this proof correct and clear enough? Or, are there points therein where it lacks in accuracy or clarity of logic?

Comment: This is perfectly fine to me